# Anchor points have different positions on different browsers

Tags: html, anchor

I am trying to create a link that goes directly to a certain section of a different page. Here is what I'm doing.

1. I create an anchor point using the name attribute:

   `<a name="fish"></a>
   <p>some content....</p>`
2. I create a link with the # added to the end
   "http://example.com#fish"

***note I have also tried the id method instead of name which still gives me the same issue.

example: `<div id="fish"></div>`

The functionality works fine and it takes me to the specific part on the page, the only issue is that it looks different on different browsers. What firefox displays is about 5 inches higher than what chrome displays.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the a tag is taking up some space.

Easiest solution, use an id instead.

```
<p id="fish">some content....</p>
```

Make sure there's enough content below so it can scroll

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have the same css default value for common html elements, however it is possible that some elements have different attribute values for padding and margin.

One way to avoid these differences is explicitly applying the values in the css statements.

```
p {margin: 10px 0px}
```

If you do not want to do this, I recommend you put link exactly in the position where text is located.

```
<p><a name="fish"></a>some content....</p>
```

You can locate the link anywhere since the anchor element will not be visible in the viewport